# how to grab strings after specified pattern sed exclude pattern after it

Tags: bash, sed

How to modify file or stdin after [split] pattern but the next [split] pattern not delimited or excluded with assuming [split] pattern can occur unlimited?

Briefly, how just first [split] pattern delimited and next not ?

use sed primarily or if cannot, use another tools like awk and other.

INPUT:

```
WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR[split]
```

I've tried:

```
~$ echo WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR | sed s/.*\\[split]//
```

and my result is:

```
AIR
```

my desired OUTPUT is like this:

```
FIRE[split]AIR
```

How can this be done please?

Comment: `[split]` is literally part of your input or is a single character like `:` or `-` etc?

Comment: I think using a tool with non-greedy regex is best choice here... for ex: `echo 'WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR' | perl -pe 's/^.*?\[split]//'`

Comment: let's elaborate (as description seems to be unclear): do you want to skip splitting on the second occurrence of `[split]` pattern and exclude all side chunks?

Comment: Is the input `WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR[split]` or `WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not creating and operating on multi-line buffers:

```
$ echo 'WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR' | sed 's/\[split]/\n/; s/.*\n//'
FIRE[split]AIR
```

If you ARE operating on multi-line buffers then you can't count on newlines or any other character not being present in the input so you have to create one (`#` below) so then to do this robustly would be:

```
$ echo 'WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR' |
    sed 's/@/@A/g; s/#/@B/g; s/\[split]/#/; s/.*#//; s/@B/#/g; s/@A/@/g'
FIRE[split]AIR
```

The first script will only work in seds that accept `\n` as a newline, with other seds use a backslash followed by a literal newline:

```
$ echo 'WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR' | sed 's/\[split]/\
/; s/.*\
//'
FIRE[split]AIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash and [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
$ foo=WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR[split]
$ bar=${foo#*\[split\]}                      # head off
$ echo ${bar%\[split\]*}                     # tail off
FIRE[split]AIR
```

- `${var%Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the *shortest* part of `$Pattern` that matches the *back end* of `$var`
- `${var#Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the *shortest* part of `$Pattern` that matches the *front end* of `$var`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo WATER[split]FIRE[split]AIR | sed 's/\[split]/[SPLIT2]/; s/.*\[SPLIT2]//'
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I recommend that you don't just post code as your answer. Please provide some kind of explanation around what way this can solve the OP's issue.

Comment: thanx for that !

Comment: Obviously that would fail if `[SPLIT2]` already existed in the input so YMMV.